# Toggle switch not running functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, toggle

I'm really stuck, can anyone help? I need to know that my toggle is working but at the moment flicking it between on and off isn't running my function? Really new to coding and could do with some basic tips!

https://jsfiddle.net/ryanphs99/aob0Lnz9/

Javascript

```
var count = 0;

$( "#flip-1" ).on('slidestop', function() {
  if (count == 0) { 
    Query.fire_trigger(12);
    count = 1;
    window.alert("ON!!!");
  } else {
    if (count == 1) { 
      Query.fire_trigger(2000);
      count = 0;
      window.alert("OFF!!!");
    }
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<h3>Fixture Picker</h3>
  <div class="containing-element">
    <select name="flip-1" id="flip-1" data-role="slider" style="overflow:hidden;">
      <option value="off">All Off</option>
      <option value="on" >All On</option>
    </select> 
  </div>
```

Comment: Are you referring to the callback function for the slidestop handler? It seems to be hitting that when you toggle.

Comment: that if inside the else seems strange.

Answer (score 0):

`Query` is not defined, so it causes an error and the script execution is interrupted before it reaches `window.alert()`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason has to do with the `Query` function.  It is undefined in that fiddle; console shows `(index):59 Uncaught ReferenceError: Query is not defined`.  When I commented out the Query function, it worked fine (alerted properly).

Answer (score 0):

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/aob0Lnz9/3/)

```
var count = 0;

$( "#flip-1" ).on('slidestop', function(){

  if (count == 0){ 
    //Query.fire_trigger(12);
    count = 1;
     window.alert("ON!!!");
  }else{

    if (count == 1){ 
      //Query.fire_trigger(2000);
      count = 0;
      window.alert("OFF!!!");
    }
  }

});
```